# jquery select all checkbox doesn't trigger change event on individual checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, event-handling

I have a `selectAll` checkbox that, when clicked, checks/unchecks all other checkboxes with class name `all_serp_results_selector`.

```
<p>Select All</p>
<input type="checkbox" id="selectAll">

<p> Individual checkboxes </p>
<input type="checkbox" class="all_serp_results_selector">
<input type="checkbox" class="all_serp_results_selector">
<input type="checkbox" class="all_serp_results_selector">
<input type="checkbox" class="all_serp_results_selector">
```

Jquery scripts:

```
$("#selectAll").on( "click", function(e) {
    $(':checkbox.all_serp_results_selector').prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

When these individual checkboxes are changed, this event handler is called:

```
$('.all_serp_results_selector').on('change', function() {
    console.log('changed');
});
```

But `selectAll` only checks/unchecks these checkboxes and doesn't trigger this event handler.

How can I make `selectAll` to also trigger change event for each individual checkboxes?

Here's jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/92gem6zr/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `change` event is only triggered automatically when the user changes the element, not when it's changed from code. You need to trigger the event explicitly.

```
$("#selectAll").on( "click", function(e) {
    $(':checkbox.all_serp_results_selector').prop('checked', this.checked).change();
});
```